# ¿Compartir dominio y certificado https?

Tags: php, nodejs, rest, https

He desarrollado una api REST con node.js y me gustaría alojarlo en un dominio que tengo https://www..com/api, en dicho dominio tengo un sitio web en php servido con apache y https. No se si es posible o tengo que servir la pagina con la api también o contratar un nuevo dominio y certificado https.

Soy novato aún, por lo que mi principal problema es que no se muy bien qué es lo que busco.

Gracias de antemano y un saludo a todos.

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta. ¿La API que desarrollaste en node.js está en otro dominio?

Comment: No está en ningún dominio aun, lo que quiero es usar el mismo que tengo para la web, pero claro, estoy usando otro puerto... estoy leyendo sobre el concepto de subdominio que puede que me sirva, pero, ¿el certificado https que ya estoy usando en mi web php me servirá también para subdominios?

Comment: Sigo sin entender. * lo que quiero es usar el mismo que tengo para la web* ¿a qué te refieres cuando hablas de *web*? Se supone que *la web* está alojada en un dominio ¿no? En esa misma web puedes definir un apartado para la API, por ejemplo algo así: `www.tuweb/api/...etc` o si quieres algo totalmente independiente, con un nuevo dominio, puedes contratar uno nuevo y agregarlo como dominio AddOn en tu misma cuenta de hosting, pudiendo compartir el mismo certificado SSL. Eso depende de tu hosting y si te lo permite, un hosting decente lo permite.

Comment: En BlueHost yo tengo dos dominios bajo la misma cuenta de hosting, comparten certificado SSL (gratuito ofrecido por BlueHost) y funcionan como dos dominios distintos. Además, en uno de ellos tengo montada una API, pero programada en PHP. Sería cuestión de decidir lo que quieres y montarla en la URL que te interese, y si quieres subirla en Node.js, pues lo mismo, la subes directamente en ese lenguaje.

Comment: Pues yo pienso que lo ideal sería esto que comentas A.Cedano: `www.tuweb/api/...etc` lo que no creo es que no puedo por que para arrancar una api node.js en un puerto xxxx con https pues tengo que configurarlo para ésta y si el puerto del dominio de mi web ya esta usado por el servidor de ésta no podría ¿no?, lo mismo es una soberana tontería y me estoy comiendo la cabeza de más por novato... No quiero un dominio distinto a ser posible, o al menos lo menos distinto posible, lo ideal es lo que comentaste.

Comment: No conozco Node.js, tengo entendido que es código Javascript en el servidor (como PHP, pero Javascript). Imagino que podrás hacerlo mediante redirecciones o algo así. Por ejemplo, en mi API tengo una carpeta `api`, allí tengo un `index.php` y un `.htaccess` que hace redirecciones, para que todas las solicitudes de este tipo `www.tuweb/api/` vayan a `index.php` que es un archivo que hace de controlador. Ese archivo determina los endpoints, los valida y pide los datos según el endpoint, los prepara y los manda a la vista para servirlos en formato JSON.

Comment: Es decir que en `index.php` yo puedo recibir cualquier cosa y decidir qué hacer con eso: si bloquear la petición (ojo con los hacker)  o determinar que es una petición válida y servir los datos. Eso ya es parte de la lógica que escribas en tu controlador de entrada. O sea, se puede escribir algo así en la URL: `www.tuweb.com/api/usuario/id/4` esa petición iría a `index.php` el cual determina si es válido pedir usuarios por su id o no. Si determina que sí, busca en la BD el usuario con id=4  y manda los datos en respuesta. Toda la clave en este caso es que desde `index.php` controlas todo.

Comment: Ya veo, no exactamente por desgracia, tengo que darle host, ip, y certificado para ejecutar express [https://expressjs.com/es/] con https, no me lo sirve el mismo servicio que sirve la web php... La api ya la tengo escrita.

Comment: Deberías poder instalar Node en tu hosting y desplegar la API en la carpeta que quieras... supongo. Como ya dije, no he trabajado con Node, pero no creo que sea demasiado complicado.

Comment: Usualmente se hace necesario configurar un servidor Proxy Reverso. NodeJS levanta su propio servidor web `http`. Luego, el servidor Proxy, que bien puede ser Apache, redirige todas las solicitudes de `www.tudomino.com/api/` al servidor de Node levantado en `host_de_node:3000/`. Si NodeJS vive en el mismo servidor que Apache, el `host_de_node` será simplemente `localhost`. Si vive en otro equipo o servidor, será la IP de dicho equipo o el nombre de dominio (si acaso tiene uno). En todo caso, es la forma que usualmente es realizada esta configuración. Saludos

Comment: Mauricio Contreras, tiene pinta de ser lo que necesito, Gracias! voy a probarlo y os comento :D

Comment: Mauricio Contreras, efectivamente era lo que necesitaba. Lo que hice fue seguir éste [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) para crear mi propio Proxy Reverso y eso solvento mi problema. Muchas gracias a todos <3